# How to remove gray background from scanned image

Tags: java, image-processing, scanning, sane

I wrote a small Java SANE-client for Windows using **jfreesane** library and it worked well for some time but yesterday I found a problem with scanner **CanoScan LiDE 60** - when using "grayscale" mode the scanned image has gray background and I don't know how to get rid of it. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

I ran into this problem with some other scanners and solved it by tuning the **contrast** parameter, however CanoScan LiDE 60 doesn't have one. Here is the full list of options from *"scanimage -A"* output (I tried all that relates to color except **gamma-table**):

```
All options specific to device `genesys:libusb:003:002':
  Scan Mode:
    --mode Color|Gray|Lineart [Gray]
        Selects the scan mode (e.g., lineart, monochrome, or color).
    --source Flatbed|Transparency Adapter [inactive]
        Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder).
    --preview[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request a preview-quality scan.
    --depth 8|16 [8]
        Number of bits per sample, typical values are 1 for "line-art" and 8
        for multibit scans.
    --resolution 1200|600|300|150|75dpi [75]
        Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
  Geometry:
    -l 0..218mm [0]
        Top-left x position of scan area.
    -t 0..299mm [0]
        Top-left y position of scan area.
    -x 0..218mm [218]
        Width of scan-area.
    -y 0..299mm [299]
        Height of scan-area.
  Enhancement:
    --custom-gamma[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Determines whether a builtin or a custom gamma-table should be used.
    --gamma-table 0..65535,... [inactive]
        Gamma-correction table.  In color mode this option equally affects the
        red, green, and blue channels simultaneously (i.e., it is an intensity
        gamma table).
    --red-gamma-table 0..65535,... [inactive]
        Gamma-correction table for the red band.
    --green-gamma-table 0..65535,... [inactive]
        Gamma-correction table for the green band.
    --blue-gamma-table 0..65535,... [inactive]
        Gamma-correction table for the blue band.
    --swdeskew[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request backend to rotate skewed pages digitally
    --swcrop[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request backend to remove border from pages digitally
    --swdespeck[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request backend to remove lone dots digitally
    --despeck 1..9 (in steps of 1) [1]
        Maximum diameter of lone dots to remove from scan
    --swskip 0..100% (in steps of 1) [0]
        Request driver to discard pages with low numbers of dark pixels
    --swderotate[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request driver to detect and correct 90 degree image rotation
  Extras:
    --lamp-off-time 0..60 [15]
        The lamp will be turned off after the given time (in minutes). A value
        of 0 means, that the lamp won't be turned off.
    --lamp-off-scan[=(yes|no)] [no]
        The lamp will be turned off during scan.
    --threshold 0..100% (in steps of 1) [50]
        Select minimum-brightness to get a white point
    --threshold-curve 0..127 (in steps of 1) [50]
        Dynamic threshold curve, from light to dark, normally 50-65
    --disable-dynamic-lineart[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Disable use of a software adaptive algorithm to generate lineart
        relying instead on hardware lineart.
    --disable-interpolation[=(yes|no)] [no]
        When using high resolutions where the horizontal resolution is smaller
        than the vertical resolution this disables horizontal interpolation.
    --color-filter Red|Green|Blue|None [None]
        When using gray or lineart this option selects the used color.
  Sensors:
  Buttons:
    --clear-calibration
        Clear calibration cache
```

And here's an interesting thing:  **Simple Scan** (Linux scanning program) somehow manages to remove gray from image with this scanner:

[image]

I'm not sure if it uses some post-scan processing or if it knows how to tell the scanner about contrast. If it's the former, are there any Java libraries that can remove this gray noise?

Comment: I suspect Simple Scan uses post processing and just binarizes the image. That is: set a Threshold, any pixel with grey-val > t set to 255, else set to 0. You did try lineart mode, didn't you?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I tried lineart with different threshold values but the result was awful: black dots and stains all over the image and the letters become "sharp".

Comment: With Lineart mode, did you try to play around with despeckle? (--swdespeck and --despeck)

Comment: Cleaning scan-results is an art, you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I did end up with this function (the contrast formula was taken from [here](http://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/)):

```
public void processImage(BufferedImage bimg, int brightness, int contrast, int t_black, int t_white) {
        Color c;
        int r, g, b;
        float factor = (259f * (contrast + 255f)) / (255f * (259f - contrast));

        for (int x = 0; x < bimg.getWidth(); x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < bimg.getHeight(); y++) {
                c = new Color(bimg.getRGB(x, y));
                // apply brightness and contrast
                r = Math.round(factor * (c.getRed() - 128) + 128) + brightness;
                g = Math.round(factor * (c.getGreen() - 128) + 128) + brightness;
                b = Math.round(factor * (c.getBlue() - 128) + 128) + brightness;
                // limit to [0, 255] range
                r = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, r));
                g = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, g));
                b = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, b));
                // apply black and white thresholds
                if (r < t_black && g < t_black && b < t_black)
                    bimg.setRGB(x, y, 0);
                else if (r > t_white && g > t_white && b > t_white)
                    bimg.setRGB(x, y, 255 << 16 | 255 << 8 | 255);
                else
                    bimg.setRGB(x, y, r << 16 | g << 8 | b);
            }
    }
```